# How can I perfectly make a loop inside a loop which also inside another loop?

Tags: c, loops

I need to make a program which looks like this:

```
Player name 1:   <input> 
Player name 2:   <input> 
<output> <output> 
(Player 1's)Score1: <input1>
            Score2: <input2> 
(player 2's)Score1: <input1>
            Score2: <input2>

(player 1's)<output1>
            <output2> 
(player 2's)<output1>
            <output2>
```

---

or Precisely:

```
Number     Player Name     Score
                           Game1     Game2
------     -----------    -------   -------
 [1]         <name1>      <score1>  <score2> 
 [2]         <name2>      <score1>  <score2>
```

---

I need to make a loop to indicate the number beside the name but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
int main()

{
    int x=1;
    char player[PLAYERS][LENGTH] = {"-----"};
    char scorex[GAME][LENGTH] = {"0.00"};

    int i,j;//COUNTERS

    for (i=0; i<PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        printf("Player Name %d:\t",x);
        fgets(player[i], LENGTH, stdin);
        x++;
    }   

    for (i=0;i<PLAYERS;i++)
    {
        printf("%10s\n", player[i]);
    }

    for (x=1; x<=PLAYERS; x++)
    {
        printf("score %d:\t", x);
        for (i=0 ;i<GAME; i++)
        {
        fgets(scorex[i], LENGTH, stdin);
        }
        printf("%5s\n", scorex[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What can I do with the loop?
Help?

Comment: Why can't you create a struct type and iterate printing everything in a single pass?

Comment: For starters, you should use more explicit variable names, such as `ixPlayer` (player index) and `ixGame`, instead of just `i`, `j` and `x`.

Comment: I am not allowed to use structures nor pointers and scanf as well.

Comment: It looks like you have to at least use stings, which are char *, right? i.e. can you at least declare something like: `char *line1[]={"name", "score1", score2"};`?

Answer (score 0):

Just addressing the output part, the following code is a way to do what you described:  (formatting needs a little work)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ansi_c.h>

enum    {
    name1,
    name2,
    name3,
    name_max
};

char *name[name_max]={"name1","name2","name3"};
char *score1[name_max]={"12","11","1"};
char *score2[name_max]={"1","13","22"};


int main(void)
{
    int line;

    printf("Number\tPlayer Name\tScore\n");
    printf("\t\tGame1\tGame 2\n");

    for (line=name1;line < name_max;line++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", line+1, name[line], score1[line], score2[line]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;   
}
```

With the following results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer using the same flavor of coding style, you can nest for loops as:

```
    for (i=0;i<PLAYERS;i++)
    {
        printf("%10s\n", player[i]);

        for (x=1; x<=PLAYERS; x++)
        {
            printf("score %d:\t", x);
            for (j=0 ;j<GAME; j++)      // << notice J not I
            {
               fgets(scorex[j], LENGTH, stdin);
            } // end for j = 0

            printf("%5s\n", scorex[i]);

        }  // end for x=1

    }  // end for i = 0
```

Note.  I didn't debug your code, just wrote nested for loops, you will need to do more work.  One of the bugs might have been in using i for an inner loop and an outer loop.